# When is it valid to convert "$\le$" or "$\ge$" to "$=$"?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I don't understand why the conversion of `≤` to `=` in this proof in Spivak's Calculus is legitimate. (The conversion in the previous line from `=` to `≤` makes sense to me.)  Could someone please explain or elaborate on how $(2)$ follows from $(1)$ below?

> this proof is motivated by the observation that
> $$
> |a|=\sqrt{a^2} \text {. }
> $$
> We may now observe that
> $$
> \begin{align*}
> (|a+b|)^2=(a+b)^2 & =a^2+2 a b+b^2 \\
> & \leq a^2+2|a| \cdot|b|+b^2 \tag{1} \\
> & =|a|^2+2|a| \cdot|b|+|b|^2 \tag{2} \\
> & =(|a|+|b|)^2
> \end{align*}
> $$
> [image]

Answer (score 9):

It is not converting anything. It is simply saying something akin to

$$1+1 \leq 2+1 = 3$$

and then concluding that $1+1 \leq 3$.

Answer (score 9):

In case the existing answers are still not clear...

1. The presentation $$
   \begin{align*}
   {}& (|a+b|)^2\\
   ={}& (a+b)^2 \\
   ={}& a^2+2 a b+b^2 \\
   \leq {}& a^2+2|a| \cdot|b|+b^2 \tag{1} \\
   ={}& |a|^2+2|a| \cdot|b|+|b|^2 \tag{2} \\
   ={}& (|a|+|b|)^2
   \end{align*}
   $$ is asserting the **conjunction** of these 5 statements:
   \begin{align*}
    (|a+b|)^2 &= (a+b)^2 \\
   (a+b)^2 &= a^2+2 a b+b^2 \\
   a^2+2 a b+b^2 &\leq a^2+2|a| \cdot|b|+b^2 \tag{1'}\\
    a^2+2|a| \cdot|b|+b^2 &= |a|^2+2|a| \cdot|b|+|b|^2 \tag{2'}\\
    |a|^2+2|a| \cdot|b|+|b|^2 &= (|a|+|b|)^2.
   \end{align*}
2. It is then natural to conclude (using transivity of `=` together with substitution of each side of the inequality) that  $$(|a+b|)^2 \le  (|a|+|b|)^2.\tag C$$

   Note that $(C)$ is generally not explicitly asserted, but just tacitly understood by the reader.
3. - Lines $(1)$ and $(2)$ are not statements, and we are ***not*** asserting that $(1)$ implies $(2)$ (nor asserting that they are equivalent, for that matter):
     \begin{align}
     \leq {}& a^2+2|a| \cdot|b|+b^2 \tag{1} \\
     ={}& |a|^2+2|a| \cdot|b|+|b|^2. \tag{2} 
     \end{align}
   - Neither is fragment $(2)$ *replacing* fragment $(1);$ the `≤` symbol is ***not*** being dropped and subsequently ignored!
4. On the other hand, given \begin{align}
   a<b\\
   b=c\\
   c>d,
   \end{align} it is invalid to draw any of the conclusions

   - $a<d$
   - $a=d$
   - $a>d;$

   in the absence of more data, any of these 3 statements might be true.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the equality follows is that, for any $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, we have

$$|a|^2 = a^2$$

Compare this against the usual definition of $|a|$:

$$|a| := \begin{cases}
a & a \ge 0 \\
-a & a < 0 \end{cases}$$

but if you square the result, in either case, you get $a^2$.

There is no "conversion from $\le$ to $=$" going on here; this is just another logical step in the proof. We know that $|a|^2=a^2$ and $|b|^2=b^2$, so the former line yields the latter.